# Handling a post and get with Yii Framework and PHP (Cannot modify header information - headers already sent)?

Tags: php, yii

```
    if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {
        $model = new User('reset');
        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
            if ($model->validate()) {
                //change pasword etc
                if ($user->save()) {
                    $this->render('reset', array('model' => $model, 'done' => 1));
                }
            } else {
                $model->password = '';
                $model->repeat_password = '';
                $this->render('reset', array('model' => $model));
            }
        }
    } elseif (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['key'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $key = $_GET['key'];
        $key_comp = ....;

        if ($key == $key_comp) {
            $this->render('reset', array('model' => $model, 'reset' => $key_comp));
        } else {
            $this->render(array('forgot'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->redirect(array('forgot'));
    }
```

I get this Error:
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

When I have updated the password, and then the page renders again with the (done variable), the key changes and hence breaks the `if ($key == $key_comp)`.

But the redirect is sending, to a different page with a render already called. This is clearly not the best method and needs some neatening but I don't think it is possible to do with a single action.

Can it be done or must it be seperated?

Comment: "headers already sent" means that there was already an output produced. Check your controller for output like spaces before your "<?php" tag, echos and remove all ending "?>" in your controllers.

Comment: I am guessing `$this->redirect(array('forgot'));` uses a `header('Location: ')` to redirect the user. I have no experience with Yii but are you writing this code in the right place?

Comment: Replace the `$this->redirect(array('forgot'))` with `echo 'blah';` and see what it s printed before the `blah`.

Comment: Probably in your nested conditions you have render before redirect